# MacBook Pro 2011 - I think we wiped my entire hard drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, internet-recovery

I think my partner wiped our entire hard dive including backup utilities etc.

Whenever I start up my MacBook I get a “no entry” or “prohibited sign” (circle with line through it).

I’ve tried booting up in safe mode with the same response, I’ve tried running disk utility and that also does not work.  I’ve tried resetting my ram with no difference.

So once I found out these results I tried re-installing via internet download but that produced a 6009f! Error (?).

I’ve tried bootable USB, however whenever I try to run it, it just restarts my computer leading me to the prohibited sign.

Any and all suggestions welcome. I don’t care about the data loss I just want my laptop back. How can I wipe and reinstall an OS?

Comment: "everything" doesn't actually tell us anything. 6003F is a network connectivity error, so oughtn't to be connected to any attempt to boot from USB or the Recovery Partition. Could you please expand your question to actually include what you tried & what the results were?

Comment: Have edited. Please let me know if this isn’t enough. Thanks.

Comment: *I’ve tried running disk utility and that also does not work. I’ve tried resetting my ram with no difference*  Huh?  How do you run DU when you can't boot?  Also, what do you mean by "resetting RAM?"  Finally...from where did you obtain/create the bootable USB?

Comment: HI Allan i may be using the wrong terminology please excuse me. What I mean is when you press Option on start up. The bootable USB I downloaded the OS on my other computer and used terminal to turn it into a bootable drive.

Comment: @Sam - assuming that the other computer is a Mac - did you test out to ensure that it boots properly?